# Create count that doesn't add duplicates over two columns

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I've got a unique question which I've spent sometime trying to find the answer for but I've found it difficult to search for.

The table below has an example of what data i'm using (date and person colum) and the answer i'm looking for (count)

| Date | Person | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2023 | Jim | 2 |
| 01/01/2023 | Jim | 2 |
| 01/01/2023 | Tanya | 2 |
| 01/01/2023 | Tanya | 2 |
| 01/01/2023 | Tim | 2 |
| 01/02/2023 | Jim | 1 |
| 01/02/2023 | Tanya | 1 |
| 01/02/2023 | Tim | 1 |
| 01/02/2023 | Tim | 1 |

I'm trying to apply a count from 1- to identify the most recent time a Person has been there. We have multiple duplicates of the same name which we need to apply the same count based on the date. Unfortunately a de-duplicate process won't work for the problem we have.
Hope this makes sense! I've tried combinations of sumproduct with count formulas but nothing is getting that result above.

Attempted multiple COUNT, COUNTIF and SUMPRODUCT formulas which resulted in either an NA, counting each individually or counting each individually within the date

Comment: Use Filter and COUNTA.

Comment: How `Tim` of date `01/02/2023` count is 1? Any explanation or it will be 2?

Comment: Please choose `Excel` OR `Google Sheets` but not both.

Answer (score 1):

Use `COUNTIFS()` with `MAP()`.

```
=MAP(A2:A10,B2:B10,LAMBDA(x,y,COUNTIFS(A:A,x,B:B,y)))
```

[image]